# Webview "safe browsing" doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, security, webview

So you are supposed to be able to enable `safe browsing` mode in Android `webview` to block malicious URL's but it doesn't seem to work.

In Chrome, it will block the example links and downloads on this page:
https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com

In webview it doesn't block anything. I also tried another site with test malicious URL's and so far haven't been able to trigger any blocking.

I've added this inside my application tag in my **manifest**:

```xml
<meta-data 
android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing" 
android:value="true" />
```

I also tried enabling it programmatically from the web settings. I'm running Android **Oreo** which should be supported.

Comment: Is this only on the emulator or does it also not work on an actual device?